# how to make a dynamic function to draw integral Graph from user input with JSXGraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsxgraph

[image: Fx from user input]

I have a problem to make a dynamic graph from this library
http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/docs/symbols/Integral.html

== this will make f(x) = x^3

```
var c1 = board.create('functiongraph', [function (t) { return t*t*t; }]);
var i1 = board.create('integral', [[-1.0, 4.0], c1]);
```

but, how can i make function(t) depends from user input ? for example user input x^2+4x from texboxt and the code will generate this:
var fx = $("#fx").val();       // fx = x^2 + 4x
var c1 = board.create('functiongraph', [function (x) { return fx; }]);
[image: GRaph FX from user input]

Answer (score 1):

JSXGraph comes with its own parser JessieCode (see https://github.com/jsxgraph/JessieCode) which does exactly this. JessieCode reads Math syntax, i.e. x^2 is converted to x*x, and hands over an object which can be plotted by JSXGraph.

Here is your example realized with JessieCode:

```
var fx = $("#fx").val();
var f = board.jc.snippet(fx, true, 'x', true);
var c1 = board.create('functiongraph', [f]);
```

Comment: oh Yeahhhh, it works bro, Thx a lot Alfred
but based on this tutorial http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Change_Equation_of_a_Graph

how to make the button image {+,-, <- , -> } appear?
because in my web, the symbol change into the weird symbol