# How to access value of integral with JSXGraph?

Tags: integral, jsxgraph

I was reading: [how to make a dynamic function to draw integral Graph from user input with JSXGraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927046/how-to-make-a-dynamic-function-to-draw-integral-graph-from-user-input-with-jsxgr?rq=1)

There the value of the integral is "-1.6667". How to access the value?

I have tried to search help, but cannot find.

Comment: This appears to be one solution. Just I cannot understand the code. How to use this for some other function such as x^2? https://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Antiderivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
function g(x){return Math.sin(x)+1};

var F = brd.create('point', [
  function(){return s.X();}, 
  function(){return JXG.Math.Numerics.I([-2,s.X()],g);}
],{});
```